# How to uniquely represent 99,999 bits as a byte, word, or double word

Tags: algorithm, hash, bit, crc

I have 99,999 bit flags that I need to represent uniquely with 32 bits or less. Any of the bits can be set and I need to know if the set bits differ from a comparable set of bits. I am considering using CRC to store a unique value hash but I am not sure if collisions will be a problem. Ideally, less than 500 of these bits will be set at any given time, but they will not be know ahead of time.

Is there suitable hash or other algorithm to uniquely represent these bits?

Comment: What you're asking can't be done. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: I am already storing all 99,999 bits. This is done on two different systems. I do not need to be able to reassemble the bits from the representative value (reverse the hash). I just need to be able to compare two representative values to determine if two sets of complete bits are equal.

Comment: Also considering lossless compression. With the majority of bits set to zero, the compression should be fairly efficient. This may require changing the prerequisite of the amount of storage necessary to represent the entire set of bits.

Comment: You have 2^99999 possible combinations that you want to represent *uniquely* in 2^32 bits. Just how do you intend to resolve collisions?

Comment: I understand the issue of collisions. I was hoping for a solution that would include collisions but with low probability to make a reasonable conclusion when comparing two sets of bits for equality. Should have stated that or provided clarification.

Comment: Err, I meant 2^99999 combinations in 32 bits (2^32 possible values). Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 4):

***NO!***

Without some other information about those bit flags to identify that certain combinations are impossible, this cannot be done.  If all combinations are possible, then you will need to use 99,999 bits to store your 99,999 bit flags.

Edit:

Based on the background information that this is to reduce network usage and the expectation is that only about 500 of the bits are set, there are techniques that can be used, but none are a simple hash, and none are efficient enough to store in 32 bits.  I would start by looking at [Arithmetic Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding).  This uses a probability distribution of the characters that you want to send (0.5% 1, 99.5% 0) to compress data.  By my computations, you can "expect" a compression of about 22 times.  But, for signals that are considered rare, you will pay the price by needing to transmit a signal larger than your starting 99,999 bits.

Comment: See comment on question. All bits are stored. Just need to compare two sets for equality.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Any hash that takes 99,999 bits and gives you 32 bits will map millions of bit combinations to the same number.  What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?  We might be able to provide an alternative solution that is feasable without this hash.

Comment: I am trying to avoid sending all 99,999 bits through the network. To just send the representative value for comparison to see if a synchronization needs to happen. As mentioned above, I am open to using compression to simply cut down the number of bits sent. That changes the original requirement of the size of the representative value. I was willing to accept collisions if the probability was low enough that two sets reasonably represented the same set. The two sets shouldn't be vastly different as changes are incremental.

Comment: "Millions of bit combinations" is a gross understatement. Assuming a uniform distribution of possible flag settings, each hash could represent ~10^10000 possible flag sets.

Comment: you can use any hashing algorithm as a first step in a verification process.  It will greatly reduce load on network.  If both hash match you will have to compare the wholes arrays

Comment: @seb considering this is to be used to check for resynchronization, that is a bad idea. If the hashes are the same, then send the entire population to run a full check; if not, send the entire population for resynchronization. All it does is add the hash to what must be sent.

Comment: Ok I missed the resynch part

Comment: Just encode the '1' indexes as a 17 bit uint and stream them.  500*17 = 8500 bits << 99999bits

Comment: @Seb Arithmetic coding should take, on average, about 4600 bits to encode.  But, with both your method and Arithmetic coding, you have the complication that the size of the resulting code varies.  Your 8500 bits assumes exactly 500 set flags.  How do you handle 400 set flags?  600 set flags?